# Possible with launch storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

The height of the upper toolbar of my photo app varies from one screen size to another...

- On 4" screens, the height is 40 points
- On 4.7" and 5.5", it's 30% of the screen height
- On other screens, it's 77 points

Considering those specifications, would it be possible to use a launch storyboard?

Answer (score 1):

In a Launch Screen storyboard you can use variations that are based on size classes. Unfortunately in your case that does not work because in portrait mode all iOS Devices share the same height size class (Regular). So size classes are of no help here.

If the Launch Screen would be a "normal" `UIViewController` you could update the height constraint of your upper toolbar programmatically. This does not work for a Launch Screen because it is displayed before you app is even running. You cannot change anything programmatically in a Launch Screen. So this does not work either.

What you could do is to set different Launch Images (depending on screen size) using your app's asset catalogue:

1. Select your Asset catalogue in the Project navigator.
2. Press the "+" and select "App Icons & LaunchImages" → "New iOS Launch Image"

Now you can add different Launch Images for different Devices:

[image]

I'm afraid this is the only way that you can address the different devices screen sizes.

Comment: I currently use Launch Images but it seems that the new iPad Pro 11" doesn't supports it. At least, I could not find the way to add it. Thanks for for your post.